# How to install ubuntu onto a wiped clean hard drive on desk computer

Tags: preinstallation

I tried to update my XP to Windows 8 but somehow everything got messed up, is it possible to format the hard-drive and just install Ubuntu? Or does windows have to already be installed? I am unexperienced with Ubuntu but would like to try it out, could use all the good answers from some of you ...  on how to do this if it is even possible.

Comment: Windows is NOT required. There's some short instructions here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop and also a howto here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Answer (score 0):

No, Ubuntu certainly doesn't need Windows to be installed. However, you will need another computer to create a USB stick or a DVD with the Ubuntu .iso on it. In fact installing Ubuntu is more straightforward if you have a whole disk to use, without the risk of overwriting a Windows partition.

And Ubuntu will format the disk for you. You don't need to do that first.

Comment: i do have my laptop as the main computer, i just need to get my desk top up and running, so if i save Ubunto onto a flash drive (USB) i just plug it in and turn on then thats it, or is there more,  sorry for the dumb questions..  my husband keeps telling me that Ubuntu is a program where you have to enter everything in that i want to do, like with the command prompts etc.  is that true,

Comment: You need to do slightly more than saving it to a flash drive: you need to use a program (I use LiLi USB Creator) to write the Ubuntu iso file to the flash drive. See the links that @ElderGeek has provided.

Comment: As for your last remark, Ubuntu has come a long way to avoid using the command line altogether. But that is a question of opinion and as such off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have the simplest case possible, just boot up the install media (write it to a DVD, or set up it on a USB key), and select in the setup options to use the whole disk. Like here:

[image]